# Update value in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have parents(P) and children(C) rows in the same table. They are related by ID and RefID connection. It looks like that (example data):

```
|        Value        |        ID        |         RefID       |        Type      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          0          |        1         |          0          |         P        |
|          5          |        2         |          0          |         P        |
|          0          |        3         |          1          |         C        |
|          3          |        4         |          1          |         C        |
|          0          |        5         |          2          |         C        |
```

I need to update `Value` column to 1 if the type = P (Parent) and Value = 0. It should also update all `Value` to 1 for the children of this parent.

The result should be:

```
|        Value        |        ID        |         RefID       |        Type      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        1         |          0          |         P        |
|          5          |        2         |          0          |         P        |
|          1          |        3         |          1          |         C        |
|          1          |        4         |          1          |         C        |
|          0          |        5         |          2          |         C        |
```

Is there a way to do this in one SQL query? What is the best approach?

Comment: The best approach is to write a query, and when that query has problems come back to SO

Comment: Are there grandchildren?

Comment: No there are not. It is only Parent - Children  (one level relation).

Comment: I think you might get this in 1 query if there are no grandchildren, or if there are a known finite number of descendent levels.  You start by joining the table to itself and then your `where` clause will be something like `where (child.Type = 'P' and child.Value = 0) or (parent.Type = 'P' and parent.Value = 0)`

Comment: Value of children cannot base on (child.Value = 0). Child should has Value set to 1 only when its parent has Value set to 1.

Comment: When child.Type = 'P', it is actually a parent.  I confused you with the predicted table alias names.  `where (T1.Type = 'P' and T1.Value = 0) or (T2.Type = 'P' and T2.Value = 0)`.  Basically it means update this row if *this row* is a parent with value 0 OR if *this row's parent* is a parent with value 0.